# How do I delete all files/driectories within my directory that are older than a day?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, delete-file

I’m using Amazon Linux with bash shell.  I wanted to delete all directories and files more than a day old in a certain directory, so I tried running this statement

```
sudo find /usr/java/jboss-as-7.1.3.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs -name "*" -type f -mmin +1441 -delete
```

However, immediately after running the above, when I check the directory, there are still child directories that are older than a day …

```
[mike@mymachine /]$ ls -al /usr/java/jboss-as-7.1.3.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs
total 240
drwxr-xr-x  17 jboss jboss  4096 Sep 20 23:24 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 jboss jboss  4096 Jun 24  2013 ..
drwxr-xr-x 186 jboss jboss 24576 Sep 20 21:12 deployment2368807199465dba
drwxr-xr-x  93 jboss jboss 20480 Sep 20 23:23 deployment2617ff35c8bff41a
drwxr-xr-x   6 jboss jboss 24576 Sep 19 20:26 deployment3571c00385713fe3
drwxr-xr-x   2 jboss jboss 20480 Sep 19 17:39 deployment3d351ede58f283dd
drwxr-xr-x   2 jboss jboss 20480 Sep 19 15:25 deployment4290f5e8ea8315f2
drwxr-xr-x 297 jboss jboss 24576 Sep 22 03:30 deployment9b31473d9eac9da0
drwxr-xr-x   2 jboss jboss 24576 Sep 20 18:56 deploymentceee45a133e7107d
drwxr-xr-x  93 jboss jboss 20480 Sep 19 18:55 deploymentefd5fbdbb2c4c444
drwxr-xr-x   2 jboss jboss  4096 Sep 20 18:57 temp165d12bb32054951
drwxr-xr-x   2 jboss jboss  4096 Sep 19 17:40 temp32dd5d98d5a4b497
drwxr-xr-x   2 jboss jboss  4096 Sep 19 15:26 temp59d119fda3e5ddc4
drwxr-xr-x   2 jboss jboss  4096 Sep 19 20:27 temp7f6ba3704ffeea57
drwxr-xr-x   2 jboss jboss  4096 Sep 20 23:23 temp861658110cf44173
drwxr-xr-x   2 jboss jboss  4096 Sep 19 18:56 tempcdad4bb17e60cb75
drwxr-xr-x   2 jboss jboss  4096 Sep 20 21:13 tempe1ee5a5f7f5c7636
```

What is the right way to write a statement that will delete everything in a certain directory that is older than a day?

**Edit:** Hey you’re suggestion didn’t work.  I got this error

```
[mike@mymachine ~]$ sudo find /usr/java/jboss/standalone/tmp/vfs/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +1 -delete
find: cannot delete `/usr/java/jboss/standalone/tmp/vfs/deploymentefd5fbdbb2c4c444': Directory not empty
find: cannot delete `/usr/java/jboss/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment3571c00385713fe3': Directory not empty
```

Comment: You're using `-type f`, which means that `find` only processes files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. It belongs on the Linux site probably.

Comment: @TomFenech - Even removing the "-type f" option still results in a "Directory not empty" error.

Comment: That's because it's trying to remove old directories but it can't because they're not empty. What do you want it to do with old directories that contain other stuff?

Comment: I want to delete it, all of it.  May it never be heard from again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the '-exec' option instead of '-delete', then you can add any command you want on each file, including a very scary 'rm -rf'.

For example, to call 'echo -n' on every file older than a day, run the following. Note '{}' is a placeholder for the found file/directory.

```
sudo find /usr/java/jboss-as-7.1.3.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs -mindepth 1 -mmin +1441 -exec echo -n {} \;
```

Edited to include '-mindepth 1', otherwise root search directory is included in results.

So, to recursively delete everything older than 1 day in the specified directory:

```
sudo find /usr/java/jboss-as-7.1.3.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs -mindepth 1 -mmin +1441 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.  I ran the last statement and it results in tons of these errors -- "find: `rf': No such file or directory".  Nothing was deleted.

Comment: Oops, there's a typo in there, should be '-exec rm -rf' . You'll get some 'file not found' warnings when it recursively deletes a folder, then tries to delete any subfolders/files, but in the end they will be gone.

Comment: The new statements prints out statements like "find: `/usr/java/jboss-as-7.1.3.Final/standalone/tmp/vfs/temp723ffd1cefda891a': No such file or directory", but the old files/directories are indeed gone so it looks like its working.